# How to include a shared library (.so) or library in a R package?

Tags: linux, r, shared-libraries

1.I have a library fpmpi . I made the shared library fpmpi.so from this library.I am using ubuntu .

2.Now, I want to use in my R package .My R package has src folder the there is makevars.in file I

```
### Setup R source code and objects.
PKG_CPPFLAGS = @PKG_CPPFLAGS@
PKG_LIBS     = -L/home/g/Desktop/Project -fpmpip

### For user configuration.
USER_CONF = Makeconf

### Start making here.
all: $(SHLIB)
@echo "MPIRUN = @MPIRUN@" > $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPIEXEC = @MPIEXEC@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "ORTERUN = @ORTERUN@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "TMP_INC = @TMP_INC@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "TMP_LIB = @TMP_LIB@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPI_ROOT = @MPI_ROOT@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPITYPE = @MPITYPE@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPI_INCLUDE_PATH = @MPI_INCLUDE_PATH@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPI_LIBPATH = @MPI_LIBPATH@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPI_LIBS = @MPI_LIBS@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPI_DEFS = @MPI_DEFS@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "MPI_INCL2 = @MPI_INCL2@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "PKG_CPPFLAGS = @PKG_CPPFLAGS@" >> $(USER_CONF)
@echo "PKG_LIBS = @PKG_LIBS@" >> $(USER_CONF)

$(SHLIB): $(OBJECTS)

clean:
@rm -rf *.o *.d *.rc *.so* *.dll *.dylib *.a *.lib \
            Makedeps Makevars $(USER_CONF) $(SHLIB) $(OBJECTS)
```

where do i define the shared library path in it. And how would i verify it has been loaded.
The library is dynamic i  have check using ldd fpmpi.so

I am using R CMD INSTALL package_name command to install package ?

The output of the R CMD INSTALL package_name is:

```
g@G:~/Documents/igauravsehrawat.github.io$ sudo R CMD INSTALL pbdMPI/
* installing to library ‘/home/g/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15’
* installing *source* package ‘pbdMPI’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for mpirun... mpirun
checking for mpiexec... mpiexec
checking for orterun... orterun
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for mpicc... mpicc
checking for ompi_info... ompi_info
checking for mpich2version... mpich2version
found sed, mpicc, and ompi_info ...
gcc: error: unrecognized option '--showme:incdirs'
>> TMP_INC_DIRS = 
gcc: error: unrecognized option '--showme:libdirs'
>> TMP_LIB_DIRS = 
I am here /usr/lib/openmpi and it is OpenMPI
Trying to find mpi.h ...
Found in /usr/lib/openmpi/include
Trying to find libmpi.so or libmpich.a ...
Found libmpi in /usr/lib/openmpi/lib
checking for openpty in -lutil... yes
checking for main in -lpthread... yes

******************* Results of pbdMPI package configure *****************

>> TMP_INC = F
>> TMP_LIB = F
>> MPI_ROOT = /usr/lib/openmpi
>> MPITYPE = OPENMPI
>> MPI_INCLUDE_PATH = /usr/lib/openmpi/include
>> MPI_LIBPATH = /usr/lib/openmpi/lib
>> MPI_LIBS =  -lutil -lpthread
>> MPI_DEFS = -DMPI2
>> MPI_INCL2 = 
>> PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include  -DMPI2 -DOPENMPI
>> PKG_LIBS = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi  -lutil -lpthread

*************************************************************************

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/zzz.r
** libs
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /home/g/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/pbdMPI
** R
** data
**  moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
‘pbdMPI-guide.Rnw’ 
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (pbdMPI)
```

Thanks

Comment: I hope this is not your complete makefile, it is incomplete. First make your package libfpmpi.so in stead of fpmpi.so and in the PKG_LIBS variable include it is -lfpmpi in stead of -fpmpip

Comment: @PeterDW It's not my makefile,it's the makevars.in file located in /src folder. The R package i am modifying is [link] (https://github.com/RBigData/pbdMPI). I have edited the output of R CMD INSTALL mypackage\